# WCF DTO-Translation with IParameterInspector?

Tags: wcf, translation, dto, extensibility

I have my own "entity"-framework with services and BL. I use different ways to publish these services (REST, Native and WCF).
Now I want a similar behavior for the DTO translation.
I am searching the proper WCF extensibility for my service layer.
Can I do this DTO translation with an IParameterInspector?

```
public class MyParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        Guid result = (Guid)correlationState;
        // ...
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            inputs[i] = DtoObject.ToDto(inputs[i]);
        }

        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

I want the Service-Interface untouched and with POCOs. My native Call should have POCOs and the ServiceInterfaces should be the same for all three ways of transportation.

---

Desired architecture

Client -> DTO translation -> transport WAN/internet -> DTO translation -> Server -> Service Call

Comment: What do you mean by "Native" services?

Comment: Binary communication with our own transport protocol